# Which PrimeFaces component to use?

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, jboss, java-ee-6

I have a requirement where I have to display & enter 24 hour values for a particular job. For a particular business there could be 100's of jobs. So basically 100 rows with 24 input fields.

I started with a datatable with 24 p:input fields, but during validations and submits I could not send more than 512 requests at one point of time. (AJAX request parameter setting in JBOSS)

I tried changing to p:cellEditor instead of p:input, but it still sends the whole form for validations.

So if some one could suggest me a primefaces component where it has a dataTable like display with multiple rows and each row has multiple input fields.

Comment: What about ajax submits? For example submit value for value with event="blur" Or change that setting in JBoss AS.

Comment: You might want to restructure the view/design. The form design you're contemplating has the potential to look very messy IMO

Comment: Use Datatable and DialogBox. Give a button in each row, on clicking the button the dialogbox should pop up. The dialogbox contains 24 inputs which you can display as whole using scroll or use jquery/javascript to hide/show next/prev group of textboxes.

Answer (score 1):

You could use pagination on the data table to restrict the no of rows you display at a time. If you use pagination with 20 rows, that should translate to roughly 24x20=480 data values.

Comment: Currently this is how I have implemented it, but business needs more rows.

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution I have zeroed down to.
Rather than submitting the whole form for validation and submission, I used ajax component to submit as user changes the value.

```
<p:inputText id="input1" value="#{row.amount[0]}" maxlength="10" size="10"  
 readonly="#{row.readOnly}" styleClass="col-right" >
<f:convertNumber  maxFractionDigits="3" minFractionDigits="3" maxIntegerDigits="5" />
<f:validator validatorId="validator" for="input1" />    
<p:ajax event="change" partialSubmit="true" process="input1" update=":#{p:component('globalMessages')}"   listener="#{controller.saveValues(row.amount[0])}"/>
</p:inputText>
```

Comment: This could still have the problem if user updates many values at the same time. This solution is assuming that the user would never update more that 400+ fields. If it is a valid assumption, then this could work.

Comment: very true..found out the hard way. This works for save and validation but if we do page navigation it fails badly.